# Using Shopify API, can I find all orders with product x?

Tags: find, product, shopify, orders

How can I find all the orders that include a certain specific product?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isnt an easy way to do this at the moment. Your best bet is to store the relationship in your own db and listen for new orders with webhooks.